# Is there a way to release resource units programmatically or do you have to use a Release block?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model with trainMoveTo blocks and am using seize/release blocks to avoid train collisions.

If I want to release the resource units of one train agent on exit track of a trainMoveTo block, is this possible with code, or would I have to break up the single movement of the trainMoveTo into:

trainMoveTo1 (to point where I want to release the resource)
-> Release
-> trainMoveTo2 (to final destination)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `Release` block, this is by design.